# ImportError: No module named 'cairocffi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, scikits

I am trying to run a sample code provided by scikit-rf (https://scikit-rf-web.readthedocs.io/) in a raspberry pi 3B. I installed all required libraries but I keep getting the error shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 24, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
ImportError: No module named 'cairocffi'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named 'cairo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Backup/scikit-rf-master/skrf/plotting.py", line 40, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .backend_cairo import cairo, HAS_CAIRO_CFFI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0-py3.5-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_cairo.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImportError("cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo "
ImportError: cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
```

I did install cairocffi using

```
pip install cairocffi
```

Entering `pip freeze` shows cairocff but this doesn't seem to help. Apologies as I am quite new to python.

Comment: Are you sure that your pip belongs to the Python executable/environment that your are using? Maybe you should be using `pip3 install cairocffi`? You try to check the paths `ls -l \`which python\``, etc...

Comment: Assuming you use `python` to run the script, then you can check via `python -m pip list` if this is the python you installed the package to.

Comment: @TomdeGeus yes, it should be pip3, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeronimo yep this instruction did help list down cairocffi once I installed it via pip3.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having trouble with different Python versions. 
Double check Python versions and see if `pip` is installing in the right locations. Once I had Python 3 and 2 installed, and `pip` was installing everything on Python 2. I had to use `pip3` for that.

Comment: That is correct. `pip` is for Python 2 packages and `pip3` is for Python 3 packages on Debian based distros, which Raspbian on PI clearly is.

Comment: pip3 was the required command. The difference between python 2 and 3 can get confusing at times. Thank you!